How to Implementing OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions API Authorization with ASP.NET Core and OAuth2 in .NET 8
How to migrate
var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

 // Sets up the token issue endpoint using the options above
 app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

to .Net 8 API
I have followed this guideline https://medium.com/web-security/implementing-api-authorization-with-asp-net-core-and-oauth2-39d883895e3a, but this is not working. I am upgrading my .Net Framework 4.8.1 API to .Net 8 API. I understand that they are two totally different technologies, but is there a way to integrate it with .net 8.
Please assist.

You need a provider that generates jwt tokens for you, such as Azure AD or Identity Server (Duende).
